# Why does my charakter in unity gets stuck in the tilemap?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

In my Unity my Player gets everytime stuck in the collider when he has a big force (If he falls from a high place, The Gravity Scale or his jumppower is high). In the picture you can see Colliders and Renderer.[image: Platformcomponents][image: Player stuck in Platform]
Only one Component is not on in screen at the platformcomponents, Tilemap.
Here is my code for Playermovement:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;



public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{


    [SerializeField] private LayerMask platformsLayerMask;
    private Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d;
    private BoxCollider2D boxCollider2d;






    private void Awake()
    {
        
        rigidbody2d = transform.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        boxCollider2d = transform.GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
    }


    private void Update()
    {
        if (IsGrounded() && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            float jump_power = 17.5f;
            rigidbody2d.velocity = Vector2.up * jump_power;
    
    
        }

        HandleMovement();
       

    }


    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        RaycastHit2D raycastHit2d = Physics2D.BoxCast(boxCollider2d.bounds.center, boxCollider2d.bounds.size, 0f, Vector2.down, .1f, platformsLayerMask);
        return raycastHit2d.collider != null;
    }

    private void HandleMovement()
    {
        float moveSpeed = 10f;

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        {
            rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, rigidbody2d.velocity.y);
    
        }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        {
            rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(+moveSpeed, rigidbody2d.velocity.y);
        }
    
        else
        {
            rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2(0, rigidbody2d.velocity.y);
        }                   

    }            

}
```

Comment: Not really sure.  Get rid of that `else` in `Handle Movement`, you are always assigning a new velocity to the rigidbody even when no button is pushed.  After you jump once, you set the velocity.y but never reset it.  So `HandleMovement` keeps applying a y direction when the jump should be over.

Comment: @jiveturkey The else in "HandleMovement" is necessary, otherwise the Player is sliding around. The rigidbody2d.velocity.y in "HandleMovement" are just saying it is not influenced.

Comment: Correct.  You need to find a different way for the player to stop movement.  Possibly set a flag on first "keyUp" and then reset y.

Comment: @jiveturkey I am a noob could you explain that a little more, please?

Comment: When the character is moving with either the A or D, set a flag, maybe `isMoving = true`.  Then instead of just your `else` clause say `else if (isMoving)` then do what you have there AND set `isMoving = false;`

Comment: @jiveturkey The problem is this only works when the Player isn't moving in the air what isn't good.

Comment: @jiveturkey Did u not know it was so simple or... no attack, thank u very much for your effort!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting the player's rigidbody collision detection to continuous? If the collision detection is set to discrete, it's really easy to come accross this kind of problem when using the built in physics system

Answer (score 0):

You need to add tilemap collider 2d component in your grid and make sure to not add composite collider and only add tilemap and tilemap collider 2d componenet